# Shortening two ASM instructions

Tags: assembly, nasm

I'm trying to shorten these instructions:

```
add eax,byte +0xc
jmp eax
```

Is this instruction equivalent to those above ?

```
 jmp dword [eax+0xc]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No.  The first adds `0x0c` to `EAX` and then jumps the the memory whose address matches `EAX`.  Note that this should simply be written as `ADD EAX, 0X0C`.

The second jumps to the address matching the content found at location `EAX+0x0c`.

Comment: How does the assembler perform the operation eax+0xc?  Does it insert the necessary instructions?

Comment: Ah, well, that's miswritten a bit.  It should just be an `ADD EAX, 0X0C`

Comment: @lurker: The operand for a JMP instruction can be an **immediate value**, a **general-purpose register**, or a **memory location**.  Since this syntax doesn't meet any of those three descriptions, I assume that NASM generates additional machine instructions to perform the necessary math under the covers. See [Effective Addresses](https://www.tortall.net/projects/yasm/manual/html/nasm-effaddr.html), which says *"NASM is capable of doing algebra on these effective addresses, so that things which don’t necessarily look legal are perfectly all right."*

Comment: It does.  It has to.  JMP doesn't have the capability of adding things together in the operand for you.

Comment: @RobertHarvey it's just a straight up memory address, no funny business necessary

Comment: Ah, you guys aren't getting it.  That's OK.

Comment: @RobertHarvey `jmp` can add just fine in a memory address, that's part of the regular memory address thing

Comment: @harold You're talking about NASM capabilities, not machine code.  I understand.

Comment: @RobertHarvey no, I'm really not. Check the ModRM/SIB encoding.

Comment: @harold Where do I find that?

Comment: @RobertHarvey the manual, also a nice table here: http://sandpile.org/x86/opc_rm.htm